# TortoiseSVN deleted status on files that are actually present

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

suddenly TortoiseSVN reports *deleted* status in commit window for most of the files in my sources folder. This makes no sense because the files are there (double checked). Well, I have been using TortoiseSVN for many years and I have never encountered such an issue. I have also restarted the computer updated to the latest Tortoise client and all the common stuff I thought that might help...

client version: 1.9.4

Thanks

//edit: Also one more interesting thing: If I open the directory in explorer, the files have this strange icon with red cross. I have not seen this icon before but that is understandable because you don't see a file with "deleted" icon very often since obviously if it really was deleted you wouldn't see any icon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items with `D` (red cross overlay icon) are *scheduled* for deletion in the repository. As soon you commit this change, the items are going to be removed from HEAD (i.e. the latest) revision. They are going to be kept in the repository history.

You used [**Delete (keep local)**](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html) [(`svn delete --keep-local`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.keep_local)) option in your working copy. That's why you see `D` when you run `svn status` for the items that are still in the working copy.

Run [**Undo Changes**](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revert.html) ([`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html)) to un-schedule the commit.

Comment: No, I did no such thing - must be some kind of bug. I have only messed with the ignore list but one of a different repository on top of that. But thanks, your suggestion with reverting the files seemed to do the trick.